# Eclipse PDT tooltip shows html tags and css inside it

Tags: eclipse, tooltip, ubuntu-12.04

Ubuntu 12.04
Eclipse 3.7.2

Also it had white text with black background but this was fixed by changing tooltip_*g_color settings in gtkrc file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0
```

Comment: Works fine in Ubuntu 12.04 with Eclipse 4.2

Comment: Works also for Ubuntu 12.10 with Eclipse 4.2.1, downloaded from eclipse.org . I think if you install eclipse from the repository you won't have this problem (because libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 sould be a dependency).

Comment: Perfect! Works also on Debian 8 with Eclipse (for PHP Developers) 4.4.2.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0
```

I had the same problem with Eclipse after upgraded my Ubuntu to 13.04.
After installed libwebkitgtk it works fine (I'm using Eclipse Kepler).

Answer (score 0):

This works for Lubuntu 12.10 running Eclipse from the repository.  Apparently libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 is not a dependency, at least not in Lubuntu.